# How to add an extension to all files via terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, file-extension

I would like to add the .zip extension to all files. I tried this, however it does not work:

```
ls | awk '{print $1 " " $1".zip"}' | xargs mv -f
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching - few links:

1. [Recursively add file extension to all files - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108527/recursively-add-file-extension-to-all-files)
2. [Add file extension to files with bash - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114004/add-file-extension-to-files-with-bash)

man rename:

```
NAME
       rename - renames multiple files

SYNOPSIS
       rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]

DESCRIPTION
       "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as 
       the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is 
       expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of the filenames 
       specified. If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will not 
       be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames will be 
       read via standard input...
```

man wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page

Comment: thx, based on that I was able to do it like this - ls | xargs -I % mv % %.zip

Answer (score 26):

```
for f in * ; do 
  mv "$f" "$f.zip"
done
```

Answer (score 22):

```
rename 's/$/\.zip/' *
```

Don't use `xargs` for that!

Comment: why don't use xargs?

Comment: Well - there's just no reason!

Answer (score 6):

A very simple way to do that is :

if you want to keep current extension:

```
for i in *; do mv $i ${i}.zip; done
```

if you want to replace current extension:

```
for i in *; do mv $i ${i%.*}.zip; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
mmv "./*" "./#1.zip"
```

(Although I have no idea why you would want to do this...)